# Error to building ubuntu touch for moka phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiling

I'm trying to build ubuntu touch for moka phone but I have the following errors:

```
host C: libext2_e2p_host <= external/e2fsprogs/lib/e2p/feature.c

host SharedLib: libext2_e2p_host (phablet/out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libext2_e2p_host.so)

phablet/out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libext2_e2p_host_intermediates/feature.o: in function "ext2fs_mark_block_bitmap":


phablet/external/e2fsprogs/lib/ext2fs/bitops.h:303: undefined reference to "ext2fs_mark_generic_bitmap"

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

build/core/host_shared_library.mk:44: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "phablet/out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libext2_e2p_host.so" non riuscito

make: *** [phablet/out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libext2_e2p_host.so] Errore 1
```

I have used this commands after syncing with "phablet-dev-bootstrap phablet":

```
. build/envsetup.sh

lunch
```

I  have choosed nr.10 for moka

```
make
```

Comment: Using which (chain of) command(s) to build?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by newer gcc version.
Minor version difference of gcc-4.8 will lead to this problem.
The later version needs inline function to be defined and implemented.
You can define NO_INLINE_FUNCS in command line or apply the following patch:

```
diff --git a/lib/ext2fs/bitops.h b/lib/ext2fs/bitops.h
index 32111ba..375d140 100644
--- a/lib/ext2fs/bitops.h
+++ b/lib/ext2fs/bitops.h
@@ -118,6 +118,8 @@ extern int ext2fs_test_block_bitmap_range(ext2fs_block_bitmap bitmap,
 extern __u32 ext2fs_get_generic_bitmap_start(ext2fs_generic_bitmap bitmap);
 extern __u32 ext2fs_get_generic_bitmap_end(ext2fs_generic_bitmap bitmap);

+#define NO_INLINE_FUNCS
+
 /*
  * The inline routines themselves...
  *
@@ -145,6 +147,7 @@ extern __u32 ext2fs_get_generic_bitmap_end(ext2fs_generic_bitmap bitmap);
 #endif
 #endif

+
 /*
  * Fast bit set/clear functions that doesn't need to return the
  * previous bit value.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have build for device manta correctly, now is time for galaxysmtd.